# Не работает элементарный сайт на html

Tags: html, браузер

Я открываю мой сайт просто кликая index.html и некоторые картинки и переходы на другие страницы не прогружаются.
Когда я его открываю с помощью расширения live server он начинает работать корректно. Почему так происходит и плохо ли это?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: можете показать вашу структуру проекта?

Comment: Ну, если картинки должны прогружаться, но не прогружаются, то по-видимому, не очень хорошо. Думаю, у Вас что-то с путями, но надо видеть весь проект